# un-bound dremora isn't despawning after I complete the conjuration ritual spell quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was playing Skyrim and finished the conjuration ritual spell quest and the un-bound dremora isn't despawning and I wasn't sure if that's supposed to happen. I've tried reloading to a previous save and  the same thing happens, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does he follow you around, or just stay there on the roof? Maybe you could just leave him up there. Also, are you on PC or a console?

Comment: Console and no he just stands there doing nothing and i cant interact with him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue across all three platforms that Skyrim is available on. Fortunately it doesn't have any real impact on your game and you can safely ignore it.

Both the [Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Conjuration_Ritual_Spell) and [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjuration_Ritual_Spell) articles list this bug. It is also supposedly resolved (or at least occurs less frequently) with version 1.2.4 of the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/?).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. it's reviving to know it wont really affect my game.

Answer (score -4):

do what this guy does in the vid to get sigil stone. Then give it to the comguring mage.

Comment: Hi, please refrain from link (or video) -only answers as these sources are known to go offline or be relocated without anyone knowing where it'll be moved to.

tl;dr - Write what the video is trying to tell you, in case that video goes down.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.